# Understanding intricacies of a simple example involving electric potential and potential energy of a system of two charged particles

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work, potential-energy, conventions

I've been studying the concept of electric potential and though I thought I had understood it, I just found myself in a tangle.

Consider a positive charge $q_s$ located at the origin of our coordinate system, and an electron somewhere in the electric field generated by $q_s$.

Consider two points A and B at distances $r_A$ and $r_B$ from the source charge $q_s$.

The work done by the electric field as the electron moves from A to B.

$$W_{AB}=\int_{r_A}^{r_B} k\frac{q_sq_e}{r^2}dr=-kq_sq_e\left (\frac{1}{r_B}-\frac{1}{r_A}\right )=-\Delta U$$

We define the potential energy function as $$U(r)=\frac{kq_sq_e}{r}$$

This function looks like

[image]

The electric potential difference between A and B is defined

$$\Delta V_{AB} = -\int_C \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{r} = \frac{-\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}}{q_e}$$

$$=\frac{\Delta U_{AB}}{q_e}$$

We can define the electric potential function as

$$V(r) = \frac{kq_s}{r}$$

It seems to me this function looks like

[image]

**Is this correct?**

But then $\Delta V_{AB}=\frac{\Delta U_{AB}}{q_e}<0$. That is, when we move from A to B, the potential energy of the electron increases, but the potential decreases. I find this confusing, though I think it has to do simply with the fact that potential measures potential energy per **positive** unit charge. **Is this in fact true?** If so, then all textbooks would be nicer if they would say this.

After all, $\Delta U_{AB} = q_e\Delta V_{AB}>0$.

As a further example, if we have a difference of potential of 1V then in this example it is necessarily the case that this difference of potential occurs when going from B to A (not the other way around).

Intuitively, such a difference of potential means that 1J of potential energy is gained by a charge of 1C. 1C is a positive charge.

In the case of our electron, if it goes from B to A, we would have

$$\Delta U_{BA} = q_e\Delta V_{BA} = q_e\ \text{J}= 1\ \text{eV}$$

Perhaps my questions and doubts above seem simple, but I think the confusion I have about the calculations has to do with signs. When we speak of voltage, we speak of J/C. It seems to be implicit that we are always writing things out in reference to a positive charge, even when we are dealing with a negative charge, as in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your doubts seem to have to do with signs. Potential is potential energy per unit positive test charge. While it might be helpful to define it as such when introducing the concepts, strictly speaking "positive" here is redundant. Charge here can be a positive or negative number (it does not refer to the magnitude of charge), and the sign of the potential energy will naturally change based on that. In fact defining potential as "potential energy per unit positive charge" seems incomplete to me, because it doesn't explicitly prescribe what to do when you have a negative charge, e.g. how to calculate the potential energy of a negative charge from a given potential.

You are correct in your description of the problem and the concepts, except for the calculation of $\Delta U_{BA}$, which should look like
$$\Delta U_{BA} = q_e\Delta V_{BA} = q_e(1\text{ V})=-|q_e|(1\text{ V})=-1\text{ eV}.$$

Answer (score 1):

From your first equation work done by the electric field due to charge $q_{\rm s}$ is,

$\displaystyle W_{AB}=-kq_sq_e\left (\frac{1}{r_B}-\frac{1}{r_A}\right )=-\Delta U \Rightarrow -\left (\frac{kq_sq_e}{r_B}-\frac{kq_sq_e}{r_A}\right )=-[U(r_{\rm B})-U(r_\rm A)]=-\Delta U$.

I have done this to confirm your working but also to point out that your potential energy function is indeed $U(r)=\dfrac{kq_sq_e}{r}$ and when graphed looks like this.

[image]

This is consistent with the potential graph that you drew.

So, what did you do wrong?
In your original derivation you assigned unsigned variables $q_{\rm s}$ and $q_{\rm e}$ to the two charges.
You then thought, "Ah, I am dealing with a positive charge s and negative charge e, so the graph I need to draw must include this bit of information.

Thus the graph you drew was $U(r)=\dfrac{kq_s\,(-q_e)}{r} -\dfrac{kq_sq_e}{r}$ where $q_{\rm e}$ is positive.

Using your potential function $V(r) = \dfrac{kq_s}{r}$ the work done by an external force (the change in potential energy of the system of two charges) in moving change $q_{\rm e}$ (unsigned) from $B$ to $A$ is $q_{\rm e}[V(r_{\rm A})-V(r_\rm A)]$ and your example $q_{\rm e}$ has a negative value as you are dealing with an electron.

Thus, in moving charge $q_{\rm e}$ from $B$ to $A$, if the potential due to charge $q_{\rm s}$ **changes** by $V$ volts, the change in the potential energy of the system of the two charges is $q_{\rm e} \times V$.

If the charge $q_{\rm e}$ happens to be an electron then $q_{\rm e} = - e$, where $e$ is the magnitude of the charge on an electron, and the electric potential energy of the system changes by $-e\,V\,\rm J$.

Comment: You are right about how I thought about the problem. From what I can see from your explanation the only incorrect part of my original post was that I wrote 1 eV instead of -1 eV, which is clear to me now. The question I asked "is this correct" was written just after the graph of electric potential. I am not sure I understand why your answer to that question is "no", given that at that point in my derivation I hadn't made the eV mistake yet.

Comment: @evianpring I have removed my first comment.  What I wanted to indicate was that without an explicit statement that $q_{\rm e}$ is negative your first graph of $U$ vs $r$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The direction of the electric field vector at point A is always defined to be in the direction of the force that a *positive* charge would feel if placed at A.  This enables the definition
$$
\vec{E}_{\textrm{at A}}=\frac{\vec{F}_{\textrm{on }q\textrm{ at A}}}{q}\,,
$$
which gives the same result for both positive and negative charges $q$ because negative charges and positives charges feel forces in *opposite* directions.

Similarly, the electric *potential* is chosen so that it *decreases* in the direction that a *positive* charge would "want" to go.  That is, the electric potential decreases in the direction that the electric field points, because that is the direction of the force exerted by the field on a positive charge. This *enables* the definition
$$
\Delta V =V_B-V_A= \frac{U_B-U_A}{q}= \frac{\Delta U}{q}\,,
$$
which works for both negative and positive probe charges because of the following:

- If a *positive* charge moves in the direction of the field, the field does *positive* work on it because a positive charge feels a force in the direction of the electric field ($\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$), in which case the change in potential energy is *negative* ($\Delta U = -W<0$). Thus, the electric potential decreases in this direction as well via the definition$$\Delta V =\frac{\Delta U}{q}\,,$$where $\Delta V<0$ and $q>0$.
- If a *negative* charge moves in the direction of the field, the field does *negaive* work on it because a negative charge feels a force in the direction *opposite* the electric field ($\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$), in which case the change in potential energy is *positive* ($\Delta U = -W>0$). According to$$\Delta V =\frac{\Delta U}{q}\,,$$we still get a  negative change in potential because now $\Delta U>0$ but $q<0$.

The upshot is the following:

- The definition $\Delta V = \Delta U/q$ works whether $q$ is positive or negative exactly because $\Delta U$ changes sign when $q$ does, so we get the same result.
- The electric potential $V$ is *defined* so that it *decreases* in the direction a positive charge "wants" to go, that is, in the direction of the electric field which is also the direction of decreasing potential energy *for a positive charge*.
- Therefore, the electric potential $V$ *increases* in the direction a *negative* charge "wants" to go; i.e., $V$ decreases in the direction *opposite* the electric field which is also the direction of *decreasing potential energy for a negative charge*.

Comment: Note: "If so, then all textbooks would be nicer if they would say this." I think if you read carefully, they do.  It's a lot to take in at once, though. Electric potential is notoriously difficult, partly because when you are learning this stuff for the first time, you are hit rapid fire with a whole bunch of new concepts, of which electric potential is the *most abstract*. In any case, remembering that the electric potential is a property of the *source* charges will help keep things straight. @evianpring